# How do I update ember.js to version 2.0.1

Tags: ember.js, configuration, upgrade, updates

I'm fairly new to ember.js

Before starting my project I wanted to upgrade my version to the latest 2.0.1 release.

I went through the steps in the [guide](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#upgrading).

```
sudo npm uninstall -g ember-cli
sudo npm cache clean
bower cache clean
sudo npm install -g ember-cli
```

typing: `ember -v` gives `1.13.8` just as it did before the 'update'

I can see that the ember-cli website says 1.13.8 is the latest version of ember-cli.
However since the [emberjs.com](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/release) site says the latest release is 2.0.1 and on the homepage the isntruction is to run `npm install -g ember-cli` I would expect the command
`ember -v` to return `2.0.1` if I was using the latest release.

I created a new ember project using `ember new test` and ran
`grep -r 'version' *` to see if there were any clues but found nothing of interest.
Looking at package.json reveals that ember-data 1.13.8 is one of the dependencies which is also not the latest version (2.0.0)

- What (if any) is the difference between ember-cli and ember.js versions?
- When I type `ember -v` the version of which program is being displayed?
- If I'm not on the latest release, how can I get it installed?

I'm running ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current version of Ember-cli installs Ember 1.13.8. You need to update your `bower.json` to use the 2.0.1 version of ember.

```
"dependencies": {
    "ember": "2.0.1",
   },
```

and then run `bower install`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I also changed ember-data to 2.0.0

Comment: I try it. But when I run "ember server"

I get "version: 1.13.12" in console

Comment: @izumeroot Did you stop and start your server?

Comment: Sure. But in console I see "version: 1.13.12". And you?

Comment: That's normal, that's the version of Ember CLI that's running. If you look in your browser, that console will tell you your version of Ember that is running.